# Elasticsearch jdbc river not indexing array

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, missing-data

Someone give me a tip.

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=TSQL2012",
    "user": "elasticsearch",
    "password": "test",
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM Elasticsearch.Analysis WHERE AnalysisID = 2800",
    "index": "jdbc",
    "type": "reports",
    "bulk_size": 160,
    "max_bulk_requests": 5
  }
}
```

I have this JSON to set up my river. And that's how data looks in my SQL Server.

[image: That's how data looks on SQL Server]

Of course, there are more records. Different AnalysisIDs with different subscriberIDs. My issue is that if I query only a few AnalysisIDs, then my SusbcriberIDs are mapped fine, however if i query Elasticsearch.Analysis without any WHERE condition, SusbcriberIDs get lost and I end up having just one.

What could be the reason behind this?
Wrong bulk_size, max_bulk_requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, but ...
You need to add "order by _id" in your query.

Comment: That's indeed strange and it solves my issue. Never could've thought about it. Thanks a lot!